# DirectX - Get Pitch Yaw Roll from XMMATRIX

Tags: c++, 3d, directx-11, direct3d

I want to do the opposite of the following:

```
DirectX::XMMATRIX Rotation = DirectX::XMMatrixRotationRollPitchYaw( m_flt_Pitch, m_flt_Yaw, m_flt_Roll);
```

So I have "Rotation" and I want to get m_flt_Pitch, m_flt_Yaw, and m_flt_Roll:

```
m_flt_Pitch = GetPitchFromXMMATRIX(Rotation);
m_flt_Yaw = GetYawFromXMMATRIX(Rotation);
m_flt_Roll = GetRollFromXMMATRIX(Rotation);
```

Can this be done?

Thank you.

Comment: The roll (x-axis rotation) pitch (y-axis rotation) and yaw (z-axis rotation) values are the Euler angles of your rotation matrix. Calculate the Euler angles and you'll get them.

Comment: Tons of pages about the subject, even on wiki. But I can't get it to work with DirectX. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: ``XMMatrixDecompose``?

Comment: Tried XMatrixDecompose, but could not get anything usefull out of the quaternion.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the most efficient way, but:

```
void ExtractPitchYawRollFromXMMatrix(float* flt_p_PitchOut, float* flt_p_YawOut, float* flt_p_RollOut, const DirectX::XMMATRIX* XMMatrix_p_Rotation)
{
    DirectX::XMFLOAT4X4 XMFLOAT4X4_Values;
    DirectX::XMStoreFloat4x4(&XMFLOAT4X4_Values, DirectX::XMMatrixTranspose(*XMMatrix_p_Rotation));
    *flt_p_PitchOut = (float)asin(-XMFLOAT4X4_Values._23);
    *flt_p_YawOut = (float) atan2(XMFLOAT4X4_Values._13, XMFLOAT4X4_Values._33);
    *flt_p_RollOut = (float) atan2(XMFLOAT4X4_Values._21, XMFLOAT4X4_Values._22);
}
```

The resulting angles may not match the original angles used to create the matrix. But together they create the same matrix.

Thank you.

Comment: This was helpful to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
float pitch = DirectX::XMScalarASin(-m_transform._32);

DirectX::XMVECTOR from(DirectX::XMVectorSet(m_transform._12, m_transform._31, 0.0f, 0.0f));
DirectX::XMVECTOR to(DirectX::XMVectorSet(m_transform._22, m_transform._33, 0.0f, 0.0f));
DirectX::XMVECTOR res(DirectX::XMVectorATan2(from, to));

float roll = DirectX::XMVectorGetX(res);
float yaw = DirectX::XMVectorGetY(res);

return DirectX::XMFLOAT3(yaw, pitch, roll);
```